# Axis labels in subplots by Plotly appear correctly only to the left subplot

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, subplot, axis-labels

I am trying to name the axes in subplots created with Plotly as shown below.  I succeed with the first (left) subplot but I can not affect the axis labeling in the other subplots. I am not clear why. How can I fix the code?

```
def bern(theta, z, N):
    
    """Bernoulli likelihood with N trials and z successes."""
    
    return np.clip(theta**z * (1-theta)**(N-z), 0, 1)

def bern2(theta1, theta2, z1, z2, N1, N2):
    
    """Bernoulli likelihood with N trials and z successes."""
    
    return bern(theta1, z1, N1) * bern(theta2, z2, N2)

def make_thetas(xmin, xmax, n):
    
    xs = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, n)
    
    widths =(xs[1:] - xs[:-1])/2.0
    
    thetas = xs[:-1]+ widths
    
    return thetas

thetas1 = make_thetas(0, 1, 101)

thetas2 = make_thetas(0, 1, 101)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(thetas1, thetas2)

a = 2

b = 3

z1 = 11

N1 = 14

z2 = 7

N2 = 14

prior = stats.beta(a, b).pdf(X) * stats.beta(a, b).pdf(Y)

likelihood = bern2(X, Y, z1, z2, N1, N2)


posterior = stats.beta(a + z1, b + N1 - z1).pdf(X) * stats.beta(a + z2, b + N2 - z2).pdf(Y)

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=3, specs= [[{'is_3d': True}, {'is_3d': True}, {'is_3d': True}]], subplot_titles=('Prior', 'Likelihood', 'Posterior'))

fig.add_trace(go.Surface(z= prior,  showscale= True), 1, 1)




fig.add_trace(go.Surface(z= likelihood,  showscale= True), 1, 2)




fig.add_trace(go.Surface(z= posterior,  showscale= True),1,3, False)

fig.update_layout(title='Prior - Likelihood - Posterior', autosize= True, scene = dict(
                    xaxis_title='theta1',
                    yaxis_title='theta2',
                    zaxis_title='Probability Density'),
                  width= 1300, height=600,
                  margin=dict(l=65, r=50, b=65, t=90))



fig.show()
```

The output of the code is this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you replace the update_layout bit at the bottow with the following code it will work:

```
fig.update_layout(title='Prior - Likelihood - Posterior', autosize=True,
    scene1=dict(
    xaxis_title='theta1',
    yaxis_title='theta2',
    zaxis_title='Probability Density'),
    scene2=dict(
    xaxis_title='theta1',
    yaxis_title='theta2',
    zaxis_title='Probability Density'),
    scene3=dict(
    xaxis_title='theta1',
    yaxis_title='theta2',
    zaxis_title='Probability Density'),
    width=1300, height=600,
    margin=dict(l=65, r=50, b=65, t=90))
```

Reading the official doc [here](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Surface.html), it does say you could specifiy layout.scene, layout.scene2 and so on, not the most obvious just by looking at the example they provided but here we go.